# Copy tensorflow contrib layers

Tags: tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
sess = tf.Session()
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
w1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, 1)
w2 = tf.contrib.copy_graph.get_copied_op(w1, sess.graph)
```

However, when I change the value of w1 using some optimizer, the value of w2 is also changed. It seems that the copy function only returns the reference of w1 instead of a new instance of it. I also tried tf.identity, which gave the same result.

How can I create a new instance of w1 whose its content doesn't change when I change w1?

Comment: w1+0 creates a copy

Comment: You mean w2 = tf.contrib.copy_graph.get_copied_op(w1+0, sess.graph) ?
w2 is still the same as w1 anyway.

Comment: I don't think `get_copied_op` does what you want. The issue is that the variables defined in the `w1` layer are updated by the optimizer; you would need to define a copy of `w1` with different variables. I'm not aware of an  easy way to do this --- is there a reason you can't just call the Python code to build the layer twice?

Comment: Sure, I can't call the python code to builld the layer twice. However, what I want is to copy the content from one layer to another layer. You can follow my another question about this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061224/duplicate-a-network-in-tensorflow/42076464#42076464). It should be clearer.