# Duplicate a network in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018010/copy-tensorflow-contrib-layers?noredirect=1#comment71210552_42018010).

However, the answer didn't satisfy my need, and no one has replied to my comment, so I have to repost the question and make it clearer.

I have 2 networks, called Target & Source. For simple, the networks are defined as follow:

```py
# Definition for Source
s_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='input_layer')
s_output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input=s_input, num_outputs=1)
# Structure of target is the same as Source's with t_input & t_output.

# Loss
loss = (alpha*t_output - s_input + beta*label)**2
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)
```

Now, after some training steps, I want to copy the content (parameters) of layer `s_output` to layer `t_output` so that `t_output` doesn't change as `s_output` changed due to the gradient descent & `t_output` still gets input from `t_input`.

I've tried the solution that Yaroslav Bulatov suggested, however it didn't work.

If I define my network using simply `tf.Variable`, I can easily copy the variable by `tf.assign`, but now I want to use `tf.contrib.layers` which is much more simpler & flexible enough to define my own network.

If anyone doesn't understand my question, please notify me so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use assign to create a copy operation, e.g.

```
s_output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input = s_input, num_outputs=1, weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
t_output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input = s_input, num_outputs=1)
```

Now you can access the trainable variables

```
vars = tf.trainable_variables()
```

and copy them (the first half are the variables from s_output and the second half from t_output):

```
copy_ops = [vars[ix+len(vars)//2].assign(var.value()) for ix, var in enumerate(vars[0:len(vars)//2])]
```

Now you can copy the data using:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session() 
sess.run(init)
map(lambda x: sess.run(x), copy_ops)
print(sess.run(vars[2]))
```

Hope this what you're looking for.

Comment: I know this is way late, but in case anybody else comes across this, u can also define the two networks using two variable scopes, and then pass the "t" scope into `tf.trainable_variables(scope='t')` to avoid having to index the variables. This will make the code much easier to understand. More info at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do the mathematical operation with tf. First, get the weight of each layer. To get weight from any layer:
My fc1 layer looks like this:-

```
with tf.variable_scope("fc1"):
    fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs = input_,
                                            num_outputs = 10,
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                            weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

To get the weight and biases of the layer the following operation can be done:`var_fc1 = tf.trainable_variables('fc1') 
fc1_w_  = np.array(sess.run(var_fc1)[0])  #get weight
fc1_b_  = np.array(sess.run(var_fc1)[1])  # get biasess`
Mimic what fc1 is doing :

```
fc1_old = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_ , fc1_w) , fc1_b)
fc1_old = tf.nn.relu(fc1_old)
```